# Ошибка на Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

После смерти, должна появиться кнопка "начать заново", но вместо этого появляется ошибка(на 2 смерти)

```
MissingReferenceException: 
The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
GameManager.Lose () (at Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs:27)
PlayerControl.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D other) 
                                 (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerControl.cs:36)
```

Не понимаю вообще, как исправить..

```
using System.Timers;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public GameObject loseWindow;
    public static GameManager instance;
    public void LoadScene(int sceneNumber)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNumber);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
    
    
    public void RestartScene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
    
    
    public void Lose()
    {
        loseWindow.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }
    
    public static GameManager Instance;

void Awake()
  {
    if(instance == null)
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        instance = this;
    } else if(instance != this)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
  }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
        public float speed;
        public float jumpForce;
        public Rigidbody2D rb;
        public bool Grounded = false;
        public Transform GroundCheck;
        public float GroundRadius = 0.2f;
        public LayerMask wtfIsGround;
        
        
        private void Update()
        {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
                {
                        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
                }
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
                {
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rb.velocity.y);
                }
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && Grounded)
                {
                        rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                }
                Grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.position, GroundRadius, wtfIsGround);
            }  
            
            
        private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
        {
                if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
                {
                      GameManager.instance.Lose();
                }
                
        }
        
        private GameManager gameManager;

void Start()
{
    gameManager = GameManager.Instance;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно у вас удаляется объект при перезагрузке сцены. Проверьте в окне объектов на сцене наличие экрана проигрыша.

Также попробуйте присвоить значение этого экрана при помощи скрипта:

```
private GameObject loseWindow;
void Awake() {
   loseWindows = GameObject.Find("Lose Window");
}
```

Comment: Объект не удаляется со сцены, но пропадает в скрипте GameManager, закинуть loseWindow, я туда не могу. Я почти ничего не понимаю в C#, не могли бы вы сказать, в какой скрипт написать код, который вы мне отправили?

Comment: это в GameManager

Comment: так, ну я написал, теперь у персонажа отключается polygon collider и скрипт PlayerControl при 1 смерти, окно проигрыша не появляется. как и куда мне скинуть скриншот? (ошибка та же самая остаётся)

Comment: оу, новая ошибка `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GameManager.Lose () (at Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs:27)
PlayerControl.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D other) (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerControl.cs:36)`